# differentiation linear map and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

let $P_5 = \{ a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3 + a_4x^4 + a_5x^5 \}$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq 5$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Denote $D: P_5 \to P_5$ as the differentiation linear map, i.e. $D(\alpha) = \dfrac{d\alpha}{dx}$

1)Find the inverse of $D^4 + D^2 + Id$,

my answer: $Id - D^2$ as $D^6 - Id = (D^2-Id)(D^4 + D^2 + Id)$

2) find a unique solution to $\alpha \in P_5$ to the differential equation $\dfrac{d^4\alpha}{dx} + \dfrac{d^2\alpha}{dx^2} + \alpha = x^5 + 2x^3$

Could someone explain how I can use (1) to solve part (2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using (1) and continue with the ODE and rewrite it: $(D^4 + D^2 + Id)(\alpha) = x^5 + 2x^3$. Apply $(D^2 - Id)$ to both sides of this equation, and use (1):

$(D^6 - Id)(\alpha) = (D^2 - Id)(x^5 + 2x^3) = D^2(x^5 + 2x^3) - Id(x^5 + 2x^3) = 20x^3 + 12x  - x^5 - 2x^3 = -x^5 + 18x^3 + 12x$. So: $D^6(\alpha) - Id(\alpha) = -x^5 + 18x^3 + 12x$, but $D^6(\alpha) = 0$, so $\alpha = x^5 - 18x^3 - 12x$